# A link for previous page in current page

Tags: drupal-6

I was trying to display a link in a page which will point to previous page the user has visited in drupal .
Previously i was using sessions

```
echo $_SESSION['back']
$_SESSION['back']=htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

This worked fine, but i was told to use variable_get and set in drupal and not to use sessions
So i did this

```
global $prev_global;
$prev_global=variable_get($prev_page,$default='http://mysite.local');
variable_set($prev_page,htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
. . .
echo "PREV:".$prev_global;
```

But this always points to the current page being viewed , what went wrong here ?

Comment: i agree with Mark...who told you this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know who told you to use `variable_get()` and `variable_set()`, but consider never listening to them again. [`variable_get()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/variable_get/6) and [`variable_set()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/variable_set/6) act on *global* variables, not user-based variables.

You had it right the first time. Use `$_SESSION`: that's what it's there for.

Comment: +1 - short lived, user specific information is what `$_SESSION` is intended to hold.

Comment: hmmm ok . but i dont think i have a say in this :(

Comment: @kantu: if someone is forcing you to use `variable_get()`/`variable_set()` for session variables, I'd be really concerned. It demonstrates a fundamental lack of understanding of both PHP and the Drupal API.

Comment: I am new to drupal i was told like " not to mess with session variables and to use variable_get _set that s what they are for !" lol

Comment: @kantu: there's a simple test case to show `variable_set()` is wrong: the variable will be the same for all users, not just the user that visited the page. Alternatively, set the variable for user 1, have user 2 visit a new page, and note that the variable for user 1 changed to the value user 2 set. As for not wanting to mess with `$_SESSION`: I don't know why that would be. It's just an associative array: it won't bite.

Comment: @NicolasBorda `$_SESSION` [works in Drupal 7, too](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/4851/7). You might have some sort of anonymous page caching that's preventing a new session from being created.